# Dell Inspiron 6000 Wireless firmware missing

Tags: wireless, drivers, dell, connection

Wireless worked in previous versions of Ubuntu, but after upgrading I can't connect to my wireless.

Dell Inspiron 6000

Service tag 8DYTN71

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following if you have a working internet connection:
Code:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter

This will install the firmware needed to help make your wireless card work.  You may want to reboot your system for the changes to take effect.

Hope that helps.